# invalid image name in cloud build when using domain-scoped project

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-build, google-iam

I'm trying to build a container with GCP's Cloud Build. I'm using the simple template from the [quickstart doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy). I've done this before successfully.

However, this time I am using a project which is under an "organization". So the project ID is `mycompany.com:projectX`, rather than simply `projectX`.

I am unable to get the build to complete.

When I run:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/mycompany.com:project-id/helloworld
```

I get the following error:

```
(gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid build: invalid image name "gcr.io/mycompany.com:projectX/helloworld"
```

I suspect that since the [`--tag` flag calls `docker build -t $TAG .` under the hood](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--tag) and [docker image names use `:` to specify versions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/), this format may be invalid.

Any ideas what I am supposed to do when working with organization projects? I cannot find relevant info in the Cloud Build or GCP IAM docs.

Some things I've tried:

- using a [`cloudbuild.yaml` config file](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config) with a `$PROJECT_ID` [substitution](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) to ensure I have the correct format
- using the project number instead of the project ID (`Using the project number in the image path is not supported. Project ID must be used instead`)
- omitting the organization name altogether, which is denied with `Token exchange failed for project`
- checking my permissions - I have `Cloud Build Editor` and `Cloud Run Invoker` roles, where the former specifies that I can "create and cancel builds"

Comment: I suspect that the repository should just be `gcr.io/projectx/helloworld` without any organizational prefixing. Is your default project set correctly? If not, try `--project=mycompany.com/projectX`. GCR implements Docker's repository API and so the naming is probably the easiest element to confirm. You can confirm the GCR settings by browsing to the repo (https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/?project=${PROJECT}`) or tagging an arbitrary image with `gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE}` and then `docker push gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE}`

Comment: thanks @DazWilkin. My default project is set to `mycompany.com:projectX`, and this is what is listed by `gcloud projects list` and `gcloud config list`. I have tried hard-coding simply `projectX` in my yaml config, but this returns a `Token exchange failed` error. Using the `--project` flag yields `[mycompany.com/projectX] is not a valid project ID`. The cloud console displays *URL not found* for both `.../images/mycompany.com:projectX` and `.../images/projectX`

Comment: I don't know why I wrote `--project=mycompany.com/projectX` that was not going to work, apologies for the misdirection. IIRC prefixing project IDs with a domain name is not related to the use of Organization nodes but is an older mechanism to scope projects to domains. I wonder if this rarity is not correctly supported by Cloud Build. Gonna call a friend. Watch this space!

Comment: I think you are adding wrong image tag here. 
```gcr.io/project-id/helloworld:tag ``` like this you have to give. Then it should be able to run. ```gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/helloworld:tag  .```

Comment: @DazWilkin looks like you were actually on the right track with `mycompany.com/projectX`. Not sure why the `--project` flag did not work for me (I could have been goofing something else up), but hard coding `mycompany.com/projectX` into my `cloudbuild.yaml` file did the trick

Comment: Thanks for the update! Pleased to read that it's working for you. Cloud Build == awesomesauce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to replace the ":" with a "/"

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/mycompany.com/project-id/helloworld
```

More info can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview#domain-scoped_projects

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by running:

```
gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/replica-20584682/helloworld --platform managed
```

now all the projects are under an organization by default and the project id is unique globally [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects) its explained this.

As it is unique globally while deploying you don't need to mention the organization.

**EDIT**
added the flag `--platform managed`

Comment: thanks @Jose, however as described in the question, I have already tried omitting the organization name like this. That yields a `Token exchange failed for project 'projectX'` error.

Comment: I did this using the CloudShell, how are you doing it?   2) This error sounds me like a roles issue, can you confirm which permissions does the account you are using for this have?  [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles) you can see the roles you need

Comment: I am running it from terminal on mac, which is how I usually create builds. My account has `Cloud Build Editor` and `Cloud Run Invoker` roles

Comment: please add ```Cloud Run Admin``` role

Comment: Adding the `Admin` role did not relieve the issue. I would not expect that to solve this issue, since the *build* is failing. I am not at the *run* stage yet. So I believe the API in question here currently is **Cloud Build**, rather than **Cloud Run**

Comment: 1)I edited the answer to add a flag that is for when is a docker image, can you try to do it like this. 2) can you try to do it though CloudShell this is to check if the issue is in the session or in your command.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone stumbling to figure out how to solve this error :

> Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: invalid build:
> invalid image name .. etc

this error accured after i deployed my app to cloud run through github .
simply do the following steps :

1. go to your triggers in cloud build
2. navigate down to configuration then click open editor
3. replace the path set automatically with your path from the error log , but make it small letters , and do not allow it to be more than 100 char