# cloud run - build : Your build failed to run: invalid build: invalid image name

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml, google-cloud-registry

iam trying to create and run a cloud trigger but every time i run it it says : Failed to trigger build: invalid build: invalid image name "gcr.io/dashs70e/prName:ef50014": could not parse reference: gcr.io/dashs70e/prName:ef50014 .

iam trying to build it using cloudbuild.yaml file

Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /nest-app
COPY package.json /nest-app
RUN npm install
COPY . /nest-app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  nest-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/nest-app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    id: Build
    args:
      - 'build'
      - '-t'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/prName:$SHORTT_SHAAA'
      - '.'

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    id: Push
    args:
      - 'push'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/prName:$SHORTT_SHAAA'

    
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - 'run'
      - 'deploy'
      - 'cld-run'
      - '--image'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/prName:$SHORTT_SHAAA'
      - '--region'
      - 'europe-west1'
      - '--platform'
      - 'managed'
      - '--allow-unauthenticated'
images:
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/prName:$SHORTT_SHAAA'
```

i go to triggers and create one then i connect to my github repo , select Cloud Build configuration file (yaml or json) from Configuration but i get this error

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `$SHORTT_SHAAA` rather than `$SHORT_SHA` [Cloud Build Substituting variable values](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)

Comment: @PaulGledhill no i have tried it with  $SHORT_SHA but got the same error so i just changes and tried again but still i get the error so i dont know where it comes from

Comment: Can you provide the command that you use to deploy your build? Please check these [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58045088/invalid-image-name-in-cloud-build-when-using-domain-scoped-project) and [Github issue](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud/issues/130) if these would address your concern.